# Python virtualenv, pip and large setupping

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

What is the best practices for management large installs of virtualenv. How to do mass update of the packages?

Answer (score 2):

On our setup we use a PIP requirements file to specify which packages are required in a virtualenv- when doing this you can also specify which versions of the packages are allowed.
Installing everything is a matter of:

```
pip -r requirements.txt
```

Then, to upgrade any of the packages we can change the version numbers in the requirements file and run:

```
pip --upgrade -r requirements.txt
```

This should also work if you aren't using version specifiers, in which case it should automatically upgrade to the latest versions on pypi.

Comment: Yes. This is useful when you have a bit environments. What about hundreds of them? How to update them all?

Comment: The wording of the question implied lots of packages in a single virualenv. For hundreds of different virtualenvs you could write a script. BUT, I would take a moment to consider what the implications of this might be. One of the main reasons for virtualenvs is to keep things stable so you don't don't break all your sites at the same time. A mass automated update of many virtualenvs seems to defeat the point somewhat.